# Using `CAST ( 1 AS BIT )` within a view

Tags: mysql, sql, casting, boolean, stored-functions

MySQL noob here, coming from years of MS SQL-Server experience.
I'm creating a view with a `BIT` column, which I understand is the correct type for boolean/yes-no columns.

The `BIT` value is computed with a simple inline `IF` statement.

```
CREATE VIEW view2 AS
SELECT
    t.column2 ,
    IF ( t.column2 IS NULL ,
         CAST ( 1 AS BIT ) ,
         CAST ( 0 AS BIT ) ) AS isColumn2Null
FROM table2 t ;
```

But when I try to execute this, I get an error:

```
Incorrect parameters in the call to stored function `CAST`
```

Why is MySQL giving a stored function error here?
Does MySQL think I am defining a stored function?
What is going on?

Apparently the `BIT` type in MySQL works differently from SQL-Server.
I tried `CAST ( 1 AS BIT ( 1 ) )` but that just gave a generic `syntax error` with no details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CAST()` cannot convert to a `BIT`.

You can emulate the behavior by treating the integer as a condition.

Basically change this:

```
CAST ( myval AS BIT )
```

To:

```
IF(myval, 1, 0)
```